# why R::Store return no thing and crash in redbeanphp?

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

I am using RedbeanPHP. I have a web host with php v5.4 and I have these lines of code :

```
 $user = R::findOne("users", "username=:un and password=:pass", array(":un" => $username, ":pass" => $pass));
    if (isset($user)) {            
        setcookie("tempSessionId", $loginId , time()+60 ); 
        $user->loginid = $loginId;  
        $ans = R::store($user); 
        echo $ans; 
    }
```

but when I execute this code any thing not print on screen.
I test my code line by line and found problem is in calling `R::store()`.
it does not return any result. 
can any one help me?

Comment: I think if (isset($user)) {   not getting any value.  Also check your sql using  R::debug(true);

Comment: I use 'var_dump($user)' and it show my beans properly :(

Comment: GOOD NEWS : i finally catch the exception. my hosting is (.......). finaly i create a simple app and my hosting create err_log file : error was this: "Call to undefined function RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\mb_strlen()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my host 'mbstring' Libdrary was disable. this was a very simple problem that create a big crash :'(